What happens to the lost part of a singly Linked list when I am introducing a loop at the middle?
I have created a singly linked list, and this is how it looks after displaying it:
19-->85-->50-->20-->33-->9-->1-->7-->null

I have created a method that can add a node to a any position of the list.
public void add_node_any(int value , int position) {
    ListNode node = new ListNode(value);
    if (position == 1) {
        node.next = head;
        head = node;
    }
    else {
        ListNode previous = head;
        int count = 1;
        while (count < position - 1) {
            previous = previous.next;
            count++;
        }
        previous.next = node;
        node.next = previous.next;
    }
}

I was trying to add a node to the third position.
single.add_node_any(2, 3);

And I realized that:
previous.next = node;
node.next = previous.next;

...is creating a loop. Also I know that due to this loop I can't access the nodes from 50 onwards. So my question is what is happening to those nodes? I have seen statements saying that still these nodes are a part of the list. They are just not accessible.
If that is still a part, how does that happen? I mean, while there is no connection between the repeating node (2) and the 50 (next in the loop), how is that possible to keep the connection with the list?
Full code
class SLL_implementation_Test_09_04 {
    private  listNode head;

    private  static class listNode {
        private int data;
        private listNode next;

        public listNode(int data) {
            this.data = data;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }   

    //Display the linked list
    public void Display() {
        listNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            System.out.print(current.data + "-->");
            current = current.next;      
        }   
        System.out.print("null"); 
    }

    //Display the length of the linked list
    public int SLL_length() {
        int count = 0;
        listNode current = head;
        while (current != null) {
            count++;
            current =current.next; 
        }   
        return count;
    }

    //Add new nodes | create a linked list from the beginning
    public void add_node_first(int value) {
        listNode newnode = new listNode(value);
        newnode.next = head;
        head = newnode;
    }

    //Add new nodes to the end of the linked list
    public void add_node_last(int value) {
        listNode newnode = new listNode(value);
        if (head == null) {
            head = newnode;
            return;
        }
        listNode current = head;
        while(current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
        }
        current.next = newnode;
    }

    //Add a new node to a given possition
    public void add_node_any(int value, int position) {
        listNode node = new listNode(value);
        if (position == 1) {
            node.next = head;
            head = node;
        }
        else {
            listNode previous = head;
            int count = 1;
            while (count < position-1) {
                previous = previous.next;
                count++;
            }
            previous.next = node;
            node.next = previous.next;
        }
    }
}

In the main method
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        SLL_implementation_Test_09_04 single = new SLL_implementation_Test_09_04();
        single.add_node_last(20);
        single.add_node_first(50);
        single.add_node_first(85);
        single.add_node_first(19); 
        single.add_node_last(33);
        single.add_node_last(9);
        single.add_node_last(1);
        single.add_node_last(7);
        single.add_node_any(2, 9);
        single.Display();
    }


What do you mean by what is happening to those nodes? They will get destroyed the next time the garbage collector runs as they are not reachable anymore.

What makes you think that that is creating a loop (cycle)?

@LouisWasserman node.next = previous.next; is the same as node.next = node

@ElliottFrisch tail->next = head in a singly link list isn't a cycle?

Guys ,I'm sorry if you felt that I miss introduce the issue. I was mentioning the word "loop"  because the node which was added is keep repeating.in this case...  if I display the list it shows   19-->85-->2-->2-->2-->2-->2.....-->2...  it keeps going. And if that's is not a loop, we must able to access the 50-->20-->33-->9-->1-->7-->null.  as well right? But its not possible.

"I don't wanna waste your time by showing the entire code." You need to show enough code that it is runnable and illustrates your question. Showing too little code wastes our time as we have to guess whether what you've posted is what you are actually running, how it is being called, and so on.

@tgdavies  Sir I have added the full code.

The nodes beyond your loop, you have decoupled them from the list, so they are no longer part of the list. Assuming you have no other references to any of them, you are right, you cannot access them in any way. This also means they are "eligible for garbage collection". Whether this means that the garbage collector will clean them up we cannot know. If your program is a small to medium exercise, I’d consider it unlikely that the garbage collector would ever run until your program finishes. In a big server program running for many days, it likely will garbage collect the nodes.


I have seen statements saying that still these nodes are a part of the list. They are just not accessible.

A reference to these statements would be interesting, but it is wrong. The node that was previous.next before your code assigned something else to that attribute, is no longer part of the list.

how is that possible to keep the connection with the list?

You are absolutely right. The definition of "linked list" includes that nodes are linked in a chain of references, one to the next. If a node is "just not accessible", then it is no longer in that chain, and by definition not part of the list.

So my question is what is happening to those nodes?

If there are no other references to the first node of the disconnected part of the original list, then it becomes available for garbage collection. This will cascade to the next node, ...etc. This makes no difference for the code, which cannot access these nodes, whether they are already garbage collected or not.
Correction
The correction is to replace this:
        previous.next = node;
        node.next = previous.next;

with this:
        listNode temp = previous.next;
        previous.next = node;
        node.next = temp;

